# Use Keycloak as multi provider for token validation

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I’d like to have 2 identity providers, e.g.:

Keycloak will be my main provider (some users will be here)

External provider will be my second provider (I’ll receive the bearer token directly)

In a future I could have more external providers.

So the idea is:

The resource server (Spring Security 5 resource-server) will receive the Bearer Token, sometimes is a Keycloak token, sometimes is an external token.

Is it possible to delegate every token to Keycloak it will discovers which is the provider and validate against them?

```
Bearer Token from Keycloak: 1234
Bearer Token from external provider: 5678

Client (sends Bearer 1234) -> Resource Server (Spring Boot MS) -> Keycloak -> Valid Token

Client (sends Bearer 5678) -> Resource Server (Spring Boot MS) -> Keycloak -> Valid Token in External Provider
```

Thank in advance

Comment: One option is to add multiple identity providers to keycloak itself, so it can be managed automatically (like ldap for internal, social media for external). Another thing just add security filter in your spring boot app, extend from OncePerRequestFilter, get header from request, check against main keycloak provider, is not, check against another, if not, 401. Filter goes to security config, http.addFilterBefore(yourFilterNameInjected, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class). All requests authenticated http.anyRequest().authenticated(). You can do it, if you understood what I said :)

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin Hi, but is it possible for example I send a token from a external auth to my keycloak and it discovers if is a token from my auth server or external auth server?

Comment: Try function through keycloak, if an exception, try another, if an exception again, return 401, if any succeded, you are authenticated.. not sure:)